# Should I create 2 different websites for mobile and desktop?

Tags: html, css

My website right now has 2 css files, 1 for mobile and 1 for desktop and I know when to load each one of them.

The question is does it's a solution for the mobile users? or should I make a total new website in another folder which is dedicated for the mobile users and even add a subdomain like m.website.com.

Comment: Why is this tagged PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try and use responsive design rather than create the m. version of the domain. At the 2014 PubCon Las Vegas, Bing representative Duane Forrester said they preferred to get rid of the m. mobile sites, instead preferring responsive. Similar statements have been made by members of Google's team. Moreover, it is less jostling for the user if they always get the same URL rather than being forced from one to another.

Finally, using the viewport in CSS will be much more effective in the long run as you won't have to keep up with browser and device detection scripts.

Answer (score 1):

From an SEO perspective, it's better to have a single URL for your website. From a development perspective, it's easier to maintain one site instead of two. It really comes down to the content on your site and if it's readable on a small screen.

Answer (score 1):

Responsive Design.

Take a look at [BootStrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)

Answer (score 1):

One website should be enough. Your CSS should be able to cater for a variety of screen sizes in order for users to view your website in an appropriate manner. BootStrap is one of the easiest frameworks to make a responsive website.
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_responsive.asp

There are a lot of different resources online dedicated to responsive web design.